# jQueryUI AutoComplete search label string length

Tags: jquery, autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I am using jQueryUI AutoComplete in a Laravel project. To limit string length I'm using this:

```
$data[] = [
  'value' => mb_strimwidth($items->product_name, 0, 50, " ..."),
  'id' => $items->id
];
```

Using this I get the output to display perfectly but the search is working properly only for a `product_name` less than 50 characters.

How can I do `mb_strimwidth($items->product_name, 0, 50, " ...")` using jQuery?

```js
$(".search_text").autocomplete({
  source: function(request, response) {
    $.ajax({
      url: src,
      data: {
        term: request.term
      },
      dataType: "json",
      success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        if (!data.length) {
          var result = [{
            label: "No Result Found!",
            value: response.term
          }];
          response(result);
        } else {
          response(data);
        }

      }
    });
  },
  minLength: 1,
});
```